# EF Core, reading a relationship into a collection and vise versa

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, uwp, entity-framework-core

I'm a bit of a beginner in EF, so apologies ahead if the question is simple.

Got a uwp project with a relationship'd data and I'm trying to implement a DB access using EF-core. The data is sort of like this-

```
class Class1
{
  public int Id {get; set; }
  public KeyedCollection<int, Class2> {get; set; }
  properties..
}

class Class2
{
  public int Id {get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("Class1ForeignKey")]
  public Class1 class1 { get; set; }

  public KeyedCollection<int, Class3> {get; set; }
  properties..
}
class class3
{
  public int Id {get; set; }

 [ForeignKey("Class2ForeignKey")]
  public Class2 class2 { get; set; }

  properties..
}
```

*The int in the KeyedCollection is the Index which I use for ease of access (I don't actually need to save it, it's saved anyway as part of the item).

It is my understanding that I cannot carry on the relationship to the DB in the current class structure. I figure I could have another list in the class, and go through that on save/ load...

But I wonder- is it possible to manually save/ load to the collection, maintaining the r/ship, without the actual list object/ property in the classes?

I tried playing with FluentAPI and overriding OnModelCreating (as shown in https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html) but no dice- I get complaints of a missing property

Comment: of course you can save the collection, as long as it is attached to your context. the sole thing maintaining your relationship is the FK property. However, it is easier to let EF know of your relationships so it can do ChangeTracking. However, I don't really know what you are trying to achieve. Navigation properties in EF have to be ICollections, you can't just add something not mappable to your POCO classes. What is the complaint you get? are you going code first?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question.

A r/ship requires:

- An ICollection, like Suichiro has mentioned. KeyedCollection implements it, so it's fine.
- A ForeignKey tag (edited my original post to provide an example). Seems like it could be optional but I didn't experiment with that.
- Include(s) on load-

  db.Class1List.Include(c1 => c1.Class2Col).ThenInclude(c2 => c2.Class3Col).ToList();

once I've fixed all those, voila.